# Error/warning messages when opening an Excel file with macro in it

Tags: excel, vba, warnings, alert, corruption

Please, I need to get rid of some messages when opening a file with a macro in it.

Note: I am using Microsoft Excel for Mac version 16.71 (Home Microsoft 365 Subscription).

First, I created a file (Agenda - composición.xlsm) with a button that calls a macro to sort some files in a agenda (I assigned the macro below to the button):

```
Sub SortAgenda_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2"), Order:=xlAscending
        
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("A2:V300")
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

*Sorry for the indentation, I am not a programmer and I was not able to put this correctly

The macro works fine once created before saving it. Then I save the file with .xlsm extension. The problem comes when I try to open it again:

1. The following alert message pops up: "We found a problem with some content in Agenda - composición.xlsm. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes." (I don't know what is the problem but I move on).
2. I click on "Yes" (I press "No" Excel does not proceed to open the file).
3. I get a pop-up with this message: "Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content."
4. I press on "View"(1) to see more details. Microsoft Word opens up (I guess the Mac gets Word per default in my case) with a document showing this message:

Repair Result to Agenda - composición1.xml
Errors were detected in file '/Users/diego_dejuan/Desktop/Agenda - composición.xlsm
Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Note: Word shows other pop-up messages that I think are not related to the macro but to Word not understanding the content:
"This command is not available on this platform."
"This file has custom XML elements that are no longer supported in Word. Saving the file will remove these elements permanently."

(1) If I press "Delete" I skip to point 6

5. I close Word and its messages and go back to ny Excel file.
6. I check that the macro still works once I press the button that has the macro assigned to it.
7. If I make changes and save the file or if I just exit the file does not fix the thing once I try to open it again. The same errors happen again

Please, what I want is to get rid of all the error and warning messages, let alone that I don't want Word to open either.

Maybe there is other macro that performing the same task does not give me the same problem? I am just trying to get rows from "A3:V3" to "A300:A300" sorted by the first three columns is ascendent order (values in column A first, then values in B and then values in C). Note that "A1:V1" are the headers, those stay put.

Comment: add `.SortFields.Clear` before the first line that adds a new sortfield.

Comment: Should the sort range be `A1:V300` for example? Also you don't need to start at A2 if you have `.Header = xlYes`.  Try using the Macro recorder to do what you want and start from there.